# Disable or hide are you sure you want to leave this page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code which redirect to another page if the button is click.

The issue is I am getting the browser pop-up "Are you sure you to leave this page", which I don't want to see in my web page.
I tried:

```
function onClick()
{
  FormData(actionName);
}

function FormData(url)
{
 var form = $('<form action ="'+url+'" method="post" > </form>');
 $('body').append(form);
 form.submit();
}
```

`window.onbeforeunload = null;` and `window.unload = null;`
but still I am seeing the same browser message.
Please help me how to avoid.

Comment: Either 1. Don't hook up a `beforeunload` handler, or 2. Use a flag to tell that handler not to set a return value. (Your `window.onbeforeunload = null` will only work for old-style handlers, not ones added via `addEventListener`, which you cannot remove unless you have a reference to them.)